# Load local array as Ajax file to improve performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables, jstl

I am using DataTables to create a table, but it is loading awfully slow. I have approx. 9000 records that need to be processed from an SQL server (php is not an option). I am using XML and Spring MVC. I am using an XML and Java to gather the data and put it into a HashSet (i have tried lists also, neither seem faster than the other).

Once I get into JS I am using a for loop to populate my arrays, then I am using that as the "data" for the data tables. My understanding is that using serverSide and "ajax" (in place of data) will speed things up significantly so I was wondering if there was a way to take my arrays and use them as AJAX.

Thanks.

Current code:

```
var InternationalSet = [];
var storeIndex = 0;
<c:forEach items="${InternationalList}" var="entry">
InternationalSet[storeIndex]= ['', "${entry.getStoreId()}","${entry.getOrderPhone()}","${entry.getAddress1()}","${entry.getCity()}","${entry.getState()}", "${entry.getZip()}", "${entry.getMgrName()}", 
  "${entry.getFranchiseeName()}", "${entry.getOrglvl6Descr()}","${entry.getCommDescr()}", "${entry.getOrglvl8Name()}", "${entry.getLatitude()}", "${entry.getLongitude()}"];
 storeIndex++;
</c:forEach>
$('#dataTable').html( '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width: 99%; color:black" class="display compact" id="tableOne"></table>' );
var table = $('#tableOne').DataTable( {
  "dom": '<l<t>ip>',
  "deferRender": true,
  "lengthChange": false, 
  "data": InternationalSet,
  "pageLength": 10,
  "orderMulti": false, 
  "columns": [.....
```

Comment: Is the database query slow, or is the JavaScript processing slow?

Comment: you might be fetching 9000 records at once, apply a pagination

Comment: Don't dump 9000 records to the UI - page through them.

Comment: pagination is applied to the datatables by default

Comment: There are examples of server side processing in the datatables docs...adjust your server script accordingly to deliver what is requested

Comment: I am not using any server script

Comment: Of course you are. That java code isn't running in browser. Instead of rendering the list into the page...you output the data via ajax calls from a different api url

Comment: @charlieftl O, well yeah ( i thought you meant like a php script) BUT, i still dont have any idea how to tie it directly to the datatable.

Comment: well that is outlined in docs and examples for plugin. Likely find a java/spring connector script for it also in a search

Comment: Have you tried adding `"paging":true,` somewhere in where you set up the table (like after `"deferRender": true,`?

Comment: I have, and the website says it is on by default. I don't notice a difference between having it there, and leaving it blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a complete answer, but a quick improvement is to populate your list as a single statement instead of 9000.

```
var InternationalSet = [
<c:forEach items="${InternationalList}" var="e" varStatus="status">
   [ '',
     "${e.getStoreId()}",
     "${e.getOrderPhone()}",
     "${e.getAddress1()}",
     "${e.getCity()}",
     "${e.getState()}", 
     "${e.getZip()}", 
     "${e.getMgrName()}", 
     "${e.getFranchiseeName()}",
     "${e.getOrglvl6Descr()}",
     "${e.getCommDescr()}", 
     "${e.getOrglvl8Name()}",
     "${e.getLatitude()}",
     "${e.getLongitude()}"
  ] <c:if test="${!status.last}">,</c:if>   
</c:forEach>
];
```

You can remove some of the new lines from the above to compactify it a little. Minor changes to the script also builds a single JSON object which you can return in an AJAX response to populate the table.

```
{
"data": [
<c:forEach items="${InternationalList}" var="e" varStatus="status">
....
</c:forEach>
]
}
```

If you are returning the data in sections from the server, your response would be changed to

```
{
"draw": ${param.draw},
"recordsTotal": ${yourTotal},
"recordsFiltered": ${yourFiltered},
"data": [
<c:forEach items="${InternationalList}" var="e" varStatus="status"
   begin="${param.start}" end="${param.start + param.length}" >
....
</c:forEach>
]
}
```

(You will have to add some range/value checking on the `param` values)

Comment: I have tried the top section of code, but I am getting errors (red squiggly lines) I have tried taking the <c: if></c: if> and the </c:for each> gets squigglied (lack of a better term)

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/t8wMerx.png

and if I remove what is underlined in this photo, the </c: foreach> gets the underline

Comment: is it faster now? which comma?

Comment: It appears to be (this is based only off the first bit of code, I will try the other ways in a bit) But initial load is appears to be about twice as fast.