# Iterate Through JSTL List By Increments

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, jstl, iteration

I was wondering the best way to approach this. I'm working on a JSP using JSTL and pulling information from a database to populate the table. My goal is to limit the number of records visible at once to 10 and have the user hit a button to display the next set of 10. Here is my HTML thus far.

```
 <table id="tableData">
            <thead>
            <th>Row</th>
            <th>Client ID</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Business Name</th>
            <th>Phone Number</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
            </thead>

       <tbody>     

          <c:forEach var="list" items="${list}" begin="0" end="9" >
              <tr>
                   <td class="selectable"><a><%= row++ %></a></td>
                   <td>${list.Client_ID}</td>
                   <td>${list.Last_Name}</td>
                   <td>${list.First_Name}</td>
                   <td>${list.Business_Name}</td>
                   <td>${list.Phone}</td>
                   <td><input class="boxes" type="checkbox" id="deleteBox" name="deleteBox" value="${list.Client_ID}" /></td>
               </tr>
           </c:forEach> 
       </tbody>
 </table>
```

Is there a way in javascript to address the 'begin' and 'end' attribute values of the jstl 'forEach loop' or is this definitely an AJAX thing? I'd rather not reload the whole page each time.

Thanks for the ideas!

Comment: JSTL is server-side, JavaScript is client-side. When the page is rendered and JavaScript can do its thing, the JSTL is gone. You can certainly use Ajax to avoid entire page reloads.

Comment: Informative. Thanks @GriffeyDog

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31700132/load-local-array-as-ajax-file-to-improve-performance/31701267#31701267) may help you. Essentially you should consider using jQuery and [Datatables](http://datatables.net/) to paginate your data on the client side.